# Application of datetime and functools is not clear

Tags: python, pandas, functools

I struggle to understand below code. Based on the documentation I read

1. `apply` invokes function `partial` on every value in the series `df['startdate']`
2. next, `partial` function passes argument `dayfirst=False` to `date_change` function (I am note sure why partial function is used here)
3. Also, data table (shown below) indicates that data looks the same: before and after (mainly order) -> *my first thought was that this function removes timestamp order in the dataset?*

```
    from datetime import timedelta
    from functools import partial
    
    df['startdate'].apply(partial(date_change, dayfirst=False))
```

Data table before and after (looks the same: shape and order)

```
0       2019-12-17
1       2019-12-18
2       2019-12-19
3       2019-12-20
4       2019-12-21
5       2021-10-28
6       2021-10-29
```

Comment: have you read [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Comment: What is `date_change`?

Comment: Initially I was looking for ```date_change``` function in the documentations (not results). However, I dig into attached files and I found definition. Nevertheless, now all is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to convert your date string to datetime?

```
df['startdate2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startdate'], dayfirst=True)
```

Output:

```
# It looks like the same
>>> df
    startdate startdate2
0  2019-12-17 2019-12-17
1  2019-12-18 2019-12-18
2  2019-12-19 2019-12-19
3  2019-12-20 2019-12-20
4  2019-12-21 2019-12-21
5  2021-10-28 2021-10-28
6  2021-10-29 2021-10-29

# But in fact, this is not the case
>>> df.dtypes
startdate             object
startdate2    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

`partial` returns a callable equivalent to `date_change` where `dayfirst=False`.

Basically, this is equivalent to calling `data_change(value, dayfirst=False)` on each value in `df['startdate']`.